# group in regex not capturing the groups as intended

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
"""<note date="8/31/12">
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading type="Reminder"/>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>"""
```

and I want to capture the open tags with groups so that I get the following output

**Intended Output**

```
[('note', ' date="8/31/12"'), ('to', ''), ('heading', ' type="Reminder"/'),  ('body', '')]
```

However I tried using this pattern
[image]

I tried using the following pattern

and the output I get is

```
[('note', ' date="8/31/12">'), ('t', 'o>Tove</to>'), ('fro', 'm>Jani</from>'), ('heading', ' type="Reminder"/>'), ('bod', "y>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>")]
```

How should I go about capturing these two correctly so that I get the intended output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second group is optional so you need to append a '?': `<([a-z]+)(\s?\w+=?"?.*)?>`.

As a general tip, look for the things you don't want to see instead of what you want to see. For example instead of `<([a-z]+)` you could capture everything until you find delimiters: `<([^\s>\/]+)`. Instead of searching for every thing you might get, search for the symbols that will definitely end your string:`[^>]+`.

So to give you a better solution: `<(\w+)([^>]+)?>`. I didn't implement the first suggestion because your tags don't appear to include special symbols.

**PS:** You should post your regex as text next time.